# HERE Maps REST API - rotation of tile labels

Tags: react-native, here-api, tiles, here-maps-rest

I'm using REST API provided by HERE Maps to display a map inside an application. As I'm not using any SDKs provided by HERE, I'm forced to fetch map tiles and render them using react-native-maps (custom tiles).

```
<UrlTile urlTemplate={...} />
```

What I'm getting is this:

[current behaviour on rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taK0C.jpg)

[regular (north up) view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWAL2.jpg)

Basically, all of the labels don't rotate on map rotation, and that makes them hard to read. Is there any possible way to handle tile rotation using only REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Tile REST API doesn't support rotation. You may try to investigate the possibility of implementing rotation in react-native-maps.